# Using An ROC Curve to Evaluate a model

Tags: r, roc, caret, confusion-matrix

I have a number of questions on the ROC curves when being used to evaluate a model.
My understanding of them is they can be used to determine the probability cutoff when classifying a row in a dataset to a class. For example if I had a dataset which was skewed 70%-30% in a class then when classifying without any investigation a good cutoff might be 70%. I am using the `ROCR` library which can be found here at [1](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/) and  [2](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/ROCR.pdf) for the ROC curve and the `yardstick` library [3](https://github.com/tidymodels/yardstick) to determine the AUC. A reproducible example is below this. I think, I understand the concept of ROC and its aims to provide a trade off between sensitivity and specificity. My questions are concerned with the implementation

My question is threefold

- Given I get an AUC of 0.699 for a decision tree does this mean when predicting new examples that I should set the value of a class to positive when the probability is over 0.699. In my example below, all people who had a probability greater than 0.699 should be assigned to the class "Good" and everyone else assigned to the class "Bad"
- If implementing cross validation, should the ROC curve be implemented on each train-test validation set and the average taken across those sets or will applying the technique to the final model be sufficient?
- Finally I seem to be having problems with my ROC graph. As stated earlier the AUC for this is 0.699 which should suggest I get a concave graph. THe problem lies with the line `ROCR::prediction(assess_dat$Good, assess_dat$Class)`. If i switch it to `ROCR::prediction(assess_dat$Bad, assess_dat$Class)` it seems to be OK. In that case is the first argument of this function the probability that a class does not belong to your class of interest and the second argument the Class you are focused on predicting?

```r
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(yardstick)
data(GermanCredit)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table(GermanCredit$Class)
#> 
#>  Bad Good 
#>  300  700
levels(GermanCredit$Class)
#> [1] "Bad"  "Good"

# I'm interested in the guys with good credit so i relevel the factor
GermanCredit$Class <- relevel(GermanCredit$Class, ref = "Good")

# create train and test set
set.seed(3456)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = .8, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)

train <- GermanCredit[ trainIndex,]
test  <- GermanCredit[-trainIndex,]

# Train the model with 10 fold cross validation
model <- train(
  Class ~., data = train,
  method = "rpart",
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10)
)

# Adds the model predictions and the model output to the dataframe
assess_dat <- test %>%
  mutate(pred = predict(model, newdata = .,  type = 'raw')) %>%
  bind_cols(predict(model, newdata = .,  type = 'prob')) %>% 
  select(Class, pred, Good, Bad)

auc <- assess_dat %>% 
  yardstick::roc_auc(truth = Class, Good) %>% 
  select(auc = .estimate)

# Have a look at the ROC curve
# Probability of predictions vs the truth
# In this case where we are trying to predict good
pred <- ROCR::prediction(assess_dat$Good, assess_dat$Class)
perf <- ROCR::performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
perf_df <- data.frame(perf@x.values, perf@y.values)
names(perf_df) <- c("tpr", "fpr")

ggplot(perf_df, aes(x = fpr, y = tpr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, lty = 3) +
  xlab("False Positive Rate") +
  ylab("True Positive Rate") +
  ggtitle("ROC Curve auc = 0.699") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# Print Results
confusionMatrix(assess_dat$pred, assess_dat$Class)
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>           Reference
#> Prediction Good Bad
#>       Good  128  49
#>       Bad    12  11
#>                                          
#>                Accuracy : 0.695          
#>                  95% CI : (0.6261, 0.758)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.7            
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5953         
#>                                          
#>                   Kappa : 0.1185         
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 4.04e-06       
#>                                          
#>             Sensitivity : 0.9143         
#>             Specificity : 0.1833         
#>          Pos Pred Value : 0.7232         
#>          Neg Pred Value : 0.4783         
#>              Prevalence : 0.7000         
#>          Detection Rate : 0.6400         
#>    Detection Prevalence : 0.8850         
#>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.5488         
#>                                          
#>        'Positive' Class : Good           
#> 
auc
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>     auc
#>   <dbl>
#> 1 0.699
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: 0.699 is the AUROC (Area Under the Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve), what you are asking for is the threshold which should be somewhere in the output / object. You can see it in the plot though (which should be reversed), the optimal threshold is slightly smaller than 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

> **problems with my ROC graph**

Try altering the labels to change the direction of the graph

```
pred = prediction(assess_dat, assess_dat$Good, label.ordering = c("Good","Class")
```